# SlideShowPro button

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

anyone know how can i make external movieclip to do: pause, on&off sound, and reward???

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've never heard of it before. Have you tried the documentation and the wiki on the official website?

http://wiki.slideshowpro.net/SSPsa/SP-SlidePress

May the force be with you,
Rob

Comment: Hi Rob,thx for your comment!
I've found pause a prevImage button. Not for sound..so i decided to use FLVPlayer Component inside flash..much easy!!
But thx a lot..and May the force be with you!!!